# Add an array to a hash entry that is already storing an array

Tags: arrays, perl, hashtable

I need to evaluate a series of strings that I want to convert into a hash of arrays. Take into account that, in this case, I want to add an array to an entry in a hash that it is already storing an array. I need to get the following hash:

```
ConfigurationHash{'Editor'} = (John, Mary, Jane, Peter)
```

I have stripped down my code to this example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %ConfigurationHash;

my $String1 = "Editor=John,Mary";
my $String2 = "Editor=Jane,Peter";

my @Line1 = split ("=", $String1);
my @Line2 = split ("=", $String2);

my $Variable1 = @Line1[0];
my $Value1    = @Line1[1];

my $Variable2 = @Line2[0];
my $Value2    = @Line2[1];

my @Values1Array = split(",", $Value1);
my @Values2Array = split(",", $Value2);

if ( ! exists $ConfigurationHash{$Variable1} ) {
    $ConfigurationHash{$Variable1} = @Values1Array;
}
else {
    push (@ConfigurationHash{$Variable1}, @Values1Array);
}
```

which produces the following error:

> Experimental push on scalar is now forbidden at ./test.pl line 25, near "@Values1Array)"
>   Execution of ./test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

I know that the problem lies in references/dereferences, but my knowledge of perl is so basic that I'm not able to figure how to get there by myself.

Could anybody show me how to do it? I would also appreciate if you could show me how to iterate the values of the array in the hash once it is created.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding some data structure basics. I suggest you read http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html

Comment: *"an entry in a hash that it is already storing an array"* I don't understand this part of your question. Your `%ConfigurationHash` is initially empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to all who posted answers. @Borodin, you're right, I missed a second block that used `$String2` and its derivatives, but I think it was obvious it was at the end and was similar to the if-else block in my original code.

Thank you, @chris-turner, for giving me the hint on how to use `push` the right way and pointing out the error in the `$ConfigurationHash{$Variable1} = @Values1Array;`

With all these contributions I figured out that the right code I was expecting is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %ConfigurationHash;

my $String1 = "Editor=John,Mary";
my $String2 = "Editor=Jane,Peter";

my @Line1 = split ("=", $String1);
my @Line2 = split ("=", $String2);

my $Variable1 = $Line1[0];
my $Value1    = $Line1[1];

my $Variable2 = $Line2[0];
my $Value2    = $Line2[1];

my @Values1Array = split(",", $Value1);
my @Values2Array = split(",", $Value2);

if ( ! exists $ConfigurationHash{$Variable1} ) {
    $ConfigurationHash{$Variable1} = \@Values1Array;
}
else {
    #push (@ConfigurationHash{$Variable1}, @Values1Array);
    push @{$ConfigurationHash{$Variable1}}, @Values1Array;
}

if ( ! exists $ConfigurationHash{$Variable2} ) {
    $ConfigurationHash{$Variable2} = \@Values2Array;
}
else {
    #push (@ConfigurationHash{$Variable2}, @Values2Array);
    push @{$ConfigurationHash{$Variable2}}, @Values2Array;
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%ConfigurationHash;
```

Which outputs the following:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Editor' => [
                        'John',
                        'Mary',
                        'Jane',
                        'Peter'
                      ]
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

This line isn't doing what you think it does.

```
$ConfigurationHash{$Variable1} = @Values1Array;
```

If you printed out what `$ConfigurationHash{$Variable1}` contains you'll find it only contains the size of `@Values1Array`.

You should be fine to use `push` but with a slight modification to what you've written.

```
push @{$ConfigurationHash{$Variable1}}, @Values1Array;
```

I've also removed the brackets as you don't need them.

As for iterating over the array, it is no different to iterating over a regular array. You were likely having problems iterating over it before as you didn't have an array

```
foreach my $whatever (@{$ConfigurationHash{$Variable1}})
  {
  # Code
  }
```

Comment: *"you'll find it only contains the last element of `@Values1Array`"* This is completely wrong. An array is not the same thing as a list. Arrays return their *length* in scalar context, and the hash element will be set to 2 in this case.

Comment: @Borodin ah, thanks for pointing that out - didn't spot that as the array I was testing with had numbers in it

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear why you have `$String2` and its derivatives in your code as they are never used. This code processes both strings

You simply need to `push` the list of values to the array corresponding to `$Variable1` (dreadful choice of identifier) in the hash. Accomplish this by *dereferencing* the array element

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %config;

my $s1 = 'Editor=John,Mary';
my $s2 = 'Editor=Jane,Peter';

for ( $s1, $s2 ) {
    my ($key, @values) = split /[=,]/;
    push @{ $config{$key} }, @values;
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%config;
```

#### output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Editor' => [
                        'John',
                        'Mary',
                        'Jane',
                        'Peter'
                      ]
        };
```